# Multiple column default value for DevExpress gridLookUpEdit

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I'm using gridLookUpEdit by DevExpress 15.2 to show data. I have already solved problem with displaying selected value with multiple columns in this way.

```
 private void gridLookUpEdit_CustomDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
    {
        GridLookUpEdit edit = sender as GridLookUpEdit;
        int theIndex = edit.Properties.GetIndexByKeyValue(edit.EditValue);
        if (edit.Properties.View.IsDataRow(theIndex))
        {
            someObject row = (someObject)edit.Properties.View.GetRow(theIndex);
            e.DisplayText = row.value1 + ":    " + row.value2 + " " +row.value3;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm using 3 different cell values to append custom display text. I would like to do exactly same thing for default value. After loading I would like to show first possible row in this pattern. 
I know, that I can obtain first row in this way:

```
gridLookUpEdit1.EditValue = gridLookUpEdit1.Properties.GetKeyValue(0);
```

Should I invoke in anyway mentioned event? Is there any efficient way to solve it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The custom display text not showing in load, because `gridLookUpEdit.Properties.View` dosen't have DataSource in load, 
You have 2 solutions to check this :

1- assing DataSource to `gridLookUpEdit.Properties.View` before select default value like this :

```
gridLookUpEdit.Properties.View.GridControl.BindingContext = new BindingContext(); 
gridLookUpEdit.Properties.View.GridControl.DataSource = gridLookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource;
gridLookUpEdit.EditValue = gridLookUpEdit.Properties.GetKeyValue(0);
```

Or

2 -You can change code in `CustomDisplayText` event like this :

```
private void gridLookUpEdit_CustomDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    GridLookUpEdit edit = sender as GridLookUpEdit;
    int theIndex = edit.Properties.GetIndexByKeyValue(edit.EditValue);
    if (theIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)edit.Properties.GetRowByKeyValue(edit.EditValue);
        e.DisplayText = row[0].ToString() + ":    " + row[1].ToString() + " " + row[2].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. Instead of values I've got a caption "Expand to check details".